# Return the enum key when decoding Protobuf in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Currently, I am decoding protobuf messages in Python where the output is:

```
{
   "lat": 12.345678,
   "lng": -12.345678,
   "firmware_status": 3
}
```

In my case 3 corresponds to `FINISHED` per the `.proto` file enum definition.  * Note I'm using v3 of protobuf.

```
enum FirmwareStatus {
  UNKNOWN = 0;
  STARTED = 1;
  IN_PROGRESS = 2;
  FINISHED = 3;
  CANCELED = 4;
  RESTARTED = 5;
}
```

How would I pull the enum "key" or definition from protobuf so that my output would be:

```
{
   "lat": 12.345678,
   "lng": -12.345678,
   "firmware_status": "FINISHED"
}
```

I couldn't find any functions in the protobuf python library to do this easily, but perhaps I missed something.

Currently, this is my decode function:

```
def decode_protobuf(uplink):
    """Decode a base64 encoded protobuf message.
    Paramaters:
        uplink (str): base64 encoded protobuf message
    Returns:
        output (dict): decoded protobuf message in dictionary format
    """

    protobuf = proto.Uplink()

    decode_base64 = base64.b64decode(uplink)

    protobuf.ParseFromString(decode_base64)

    output = {}

    elems = protobuf.ListFields()
    for elem in elems:
        output[elem[0].name] = elem[1]

    return output
```

Comment: Which protobuf version does this code use?

Comment: @MichaelRuth version 3.  I'll update the question - should have included originally. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json_format.MessageToDict` which has an option so save enums as string

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/python/google/protobuf/json_format.py#L134